# Display issue using RShiny and pyramid library

Tags: r, shiny

During my first project with RShiny, I have an issue using the pyramid library ( https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pyramid/index.html ). 
The code is executed without error, but I do not obtain display result in the shiny app.

Here is the concerned code in server.R file and UI.R file :

server.R :

```
output$effectifStartAgrege <- renderPlot({
    staff <- read.xlsx('C:/file.xlsx', 1)
    pyramid(staff, main = "Statistics")
})
```

ui.R :

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    dashboardBody( 
        tabItems(
            tabItem(tabName = "Team D",
                tabBox(
                    title = "Team detailed compositions",
                    width = 400,
                    id = "tabset2", height = "250px",
                    tabPanel("START", "First tab content",                                                      
                    plotOutput("effectifStartAgrege")))                        
                   )
        )
   )
))
```

And the output of dput(staff) :

```
structure(list(Grade = structure(c(4L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 
9L, 3L), .Label = c("AD", "AE", "AS/ED", "I", "M", "S1", "S2", 
"S3", "SM"), class = "factor"), Assurance = c(6, 7, 0, 8, 7, 
0, 7, 2, 4), Pension = c(0, 10, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 1, 2), Analytics = c(3, 
3, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0)), .Names = c("Grade", "Assurance", "Pension", 
"Analytics"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please add a bit of data (paste the output of `dput(staff)` or `dput(staff[1:20,])`) to your post so we can run the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with the `pyramid` library but with your `ui` design. See [this](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html), you need to get rid of `shinyUI` and `fluidPage`, replace it with a `dashboardPage`, add a header and a sidebar etc.

Here is an example taken from the link I posted:

```
library(shiny)
library(pyramid)
library(shinydashboard)


sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Team D", tabName = "TeamD", icon = icon("dashboard")),
    menuItem("Widgets", icon = icon("th"), tabName = "widgets",
             badgeLabel = "new", badgeColor = "green")
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
            h2("Dashboard tab content")
    ),

    tabItem(tabName = "TeamD",
            h2("test"),
            tabBox(
              title = "Team detailed compositions",
              width = 400,
              id = "tabset2", height = "250px",
              tabPanel("START", "First tab content",                                                      
                       plotOutput("effectifStartAgrege"))) 
    )
  )
)

ui <-dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Simple tabs"),
  sidebar,
  body
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$effectifStartAgrege <- renderPlot({
    pyramid(staff, main = "Statistics")
  }) 
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer NicE, this solution works with more simplicity.
However, I still can't find why one of the tabItem (inside dashBoardbody) is not displayed . It seems RShiny is catching the last tabItem found and diplays it inside the following "menuItem". I was thinking it could be coming from the id parameter of the tabBox (set by default at "tabset1"). What do you think ?

Comment: Not sure I understand, right now I see two tabItem in my display, one just has the "Dashboard tab content" text and the other one your plot. To switch between them the buttons are in the sidebar. Which one do you think is missing?

Comment: My original code had many tabItem, and one of them was not displayed in the App. It was due to a space in the tabName that caused the error, but nothing linked to my original problem. Thanks for your help !